# SQL - 1 Column Twice in the SELECT Statement for different values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relationship

I have created a database of "trips" with the following

TripParent

- Id
- DrivingCompany
- Client

TripDetails

- Id
- Destination
- PlannedArrivalDate

StatusLog

- Id
- CatStatusId (Comes from another table just with the names)
- DateTimeModified

Let me explain the tables, first of all I hid another fields to keep it simple, the "Parent" table has MANY TripDetails, so it is just a summary for the many "Details" it has. The TripDetails table its 1 row for 1 destination, let's say the Trip is going from A to C, then we have a Row for each "stop" (A, B, C).
And then we got the StatusLog table that has MANY Rows for each "TripDetails".

The problem is, I need a stored procedure that returns the DrivingCompany, Client, PlannedArrivalDate, RealArrivalDate and RealDepartureDate.

The "Real Dates" come from the StatusLog table. Status 1 means that the truck has arrived Destination (A/B/C) and the status 2 means that it has left said location.

So far I got the following

```
SELECT  
    TP.DrivingCompany, TP.Client, TD.PlannedArrivalDate,
    'Real Arrival Date' = CASE SL.CatStatusId 
                             WHEN 1 THEN SL.DateTimeModified
                             ELSE NULL
                          END,
   'Real Departure Date' = CASE SL.CatStatusId 
                              WHEN 2 THEN SL.DateTimeModified
                              ELSE NULL
                           END
FROM 
    TripParent TP
JOIN 
    TripDetails TD ON TD.TripParentId = TE.Id 
JOIN 
    StatusLog SL ON SL.TripDetailsId = TD.Id
GROUP BY 
    TP.Id
ORDER BY 
    TD.Id
```

Is using the CASE the correct way to show the same column twice in the SELECT statement? I think I'm on the right track but I can't group by TP.Id and I also need to show ALL the rows, going by this query, It doesn't show the "TripDetails" that don't have a "StatusLog" row because they haven't arrived.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TP.Id,
       TP.DrivingCompany, 
       TP.Client, 
       TD.PlannedArrivalDate,
       'Real Arrival Date' = CASE SL.CatStatusId
                              WHEN 1 THEN SL.DateTimeModified
                              ELSE NULL
                             END,
       'Real Departure Date' = CASE SL.CatStatusId
                                WHEN 2 THEN SL.DateTimeModified
                                ELSE NULL
                               END
  FROM      TripParent TP
       JOIN TripDetails TD ON TD.TripParentId = TE.Id 
  LEFT JOIN StatusLog SL ON SL.TripDetailsId = TD.Id
 GROUP BY TP.Id,
          TP.DrivingCompany, 
          TP.Client, 
          TD.PlannedArrivalDate
 ORDER BY TD.Id
```

They way you use CASE if perfectly fine, yes. Columns you want to group by must be contained in the SELECT. Using a LEFT JOIN for the log entries ensures that you get also rows without corresponding log.

When grouping, each column you display must be either contained in the GROUP BY clause or in an aggregate function in the SELECT. So you have to think about why you are grouping, do you want to create a sum, count, ... ? >> Change the two CASE columns accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, the LEFT JOIN does give me the rows even if there are no log. About the GROUP clause, even if I put the TP.Id in the SELECT, I get this error: 

**Column 'TP.DrivingCompany' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.**

This is a sample of my [DATA](https://i.redd.it/vnlkrhhqgf2z.png)

The 2 last rows should be displayed in 1 to put the Real Arrival Date and Real Departure Date together

Comment: See changed answer.